# Java: Getting if there is an element before a specified element in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public static boolean isComponentBefore(GuiInterface component) {
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < components.size(); i++) {
        if (components.get(i).getName() == component.getName()) {
            if(components.get(i- 1) == null){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;

}
```

I currently use this, though this can lead to ConcurrentModificationExceptions & it isn't working because it keeps throwing ConcurrentModificationExceptions whenever I try to see if the element before the element passed in is null.

I was wondering if there are other ways to do this.

Comment: Why are you adding `null` into your `ArrayList` anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an iterator

e.g

```
    int i = 0;
    Iterator<GuiInterface > it = components.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        i++;
        GuiInterface  thisComp = it.next (); 
        if (thisComp.getName().equals(component.getName())) {
          if(i > 0 && components.get(i- 1) == null){  // this code does not make sense
            return false;
          }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
if (components.get(i).getName() == component.getName()) {
```

Should be

```
if (components.get(i).getName().equals(component.getName())) {
```

However, your condition can never happen. If `component.get(i-1)` is null, then in the previous loop iteration

```
components.get(i).getName() // <-- null pointer exception, so
```

`component.get(i-1)` must not be null and you need to hope that `i` isn't `0` or you'd get an index out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your logic, you will a `NullPointerException` incase the component in the `ArrayList` before the given component is `null`, because `components.get(i)` would be `null` and `components.get(i).getName()` will throw the NPE.

You can try to change the logic here a bit. For every null element in the list, check if the next component is the component you're searching for and return accordingly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < components.size(); i++) {
    if (components.get(i) == null) { // If a particular element is null, check if the next element is what you want
        if(components.get(i+1).getName().equals(component.getName())) { // you need to handle the edge case for i+1 as well for the last iteration
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you need to compare the Strings using `equals()` method and not the `==` operator. You also need to handle the corner case of `i+1` for the last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the passed component is not in your list:

```
public static boolean isComponentBefore(GUIComponent component) {

    // Start at 1 to avoid IndexOutOfBounds
    for(int i = 1; i < components.size(); i++) {
        if (components.get(i).getName().equals(component.getName())) {
            return components.get(i - 1) != null;
        }
    }

    // Given component is not in the list, or the list only has one element
    return false;
}
```

Assuming the passed component *is* in the list:

```
public static boolean isComponentBefore(GUIComponent component) {
    int index = components.indexOf(component);

    return index > 0 && components.get(index - 1) != null;
}
```